# Why is asking questions so hard?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I try asking questions, but somebody has to block me. I read How Do I Ask A Good Question, but I would like to know why. Not every site makes it super hard to ask questions.

Comment: Not every site has the same quality of content either. The reason there are certain expectations from someone asking a question is to prevent driving away the people who spend their free time answering them.

Comment: I looked at two questions you asked and both seemed poor to me. Please read the help pages again. These help pages http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask may help to explain more clearly why the two questions were closed.

Comment: You could also ask for advice here on how to improve those two questions, people do that fairly often and tend to get some good advice. It would also be a lot more constructive than coming across as "why is it so hard".

Comment: You obviously weren't blocked for asking questions since you originally asked this question on Stack Overflow.  But I'm going to guess you are probably blocked now given your undeleted question history.  And chances are you are blocked from answering questions too.

Comment: but unfortunately you look like you are treating Stack Overflow as a common forum.  We don't accept just any question under the sun and answers are expected to have a certain level of quality.  For example, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27214261/250725) is completely off-topic.  You have to assume that if someone is asking a question on Stack Overflow then they are looking for a **programmatic** solution.  The you should expect the asker to have enough knowledge to know how to convert a file manually.

Comment: The answer is "Quality". And keep in mind that primarily we're not necessarily here to help you. We're here to build a great resource of well-asked questions and great answers. That's the real goal. So we expect you to ask questions that aren't just to help you out of a tricky situation, but that are of use to others as well. And we do the best we can to keep quality high. Helping you in the process is a great side-effect.

Comment: As for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27214039/in-assembly-how-do-you-connect-the-american-keyboard-to-print-out-text).  In theory, the topic could be on-topic here, but how to asked it is both way to broad and unclear.  (1) what kind of interface do you want to use? (2) what controller do you have? (3) what have you tried on your own? {4} where are you stuck?  --- you can't just expect someone to give you a complete answer to such a vague question.  We don't provide links to tutorials or tools either.  So you need a focused question about a specific problem.

Comment: `Why is asking questions so hard`: ask your self why are you here?  It is probably because there are so many good/helpful answers.  Good Answers cant come from poor questions, so there are standards.

Comment: @Plutonix That last sentence is incorrect sans "so there are standards." Good answers on bad questions happen all the time - we even have badges for it.

Answer (score 16):

You asked 2 questions, and answered 2 others. It's a bit unfair to draw conclusions that fast. You did not even read the [Introductory Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

One question is asking for resources, which is Off Topic because it may lead to spam, opinionated answers (a discussion on "what is the *best*), links (which may get stale over time), et cetera. I don't think that question is salvageable.

The other question is *way* too vague. The downvotes and Close Votes indicate people have problems in understanding your question. Edit that post, adding the missing relevant information (e.g., what did you try; why do you need to attach a keyboard to print out text), and if it's a better question then people will vote to re-open it.

Your 2 answers are very minimal. "Try this" is usually best put in a comment, because it suggests you don't *know* the answer. (And if you do, use "Use this"; with an explanation *why*.) You can only comment with a slightly higher reputation, so to avoid downvotes (because the answers are considered "bad") just restrain yourself and don't answer such questions. Look for ones you *can* answer with some confidence.

On the whole I'd say that your assumption "we" (Stack Overflow readers) are making it hard to ask questions is correct. "Easy" questions that can easily be answered by a simple web search are frowned upon. "Broad" questions are off-topic because SO is not a we-write-you-a-tutorial site. "Give me the codes" questions are not on topic because we expect people to *learn*. And so on.

1. Improve your existing posts; both questions and answers.
2. Keep on answering, but stay away from "try this" -- a good way to earn reputation is writing a *solid* answer, backed up (if necessary) by links or quotes to background information, and tested so you are sure it works.
3. Before asking a new question, please read the guides. They are to help you, not to hinder you.